# How to stop full page postback in asp.net ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, file-upload, updatepanel

I have a `fileupload control` in `Updatepanel`. It only works when i register `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddPersonalInformation" />` in triggers but the problem is that it refreshes whole page which I don't want to. How to stop this full page upload. I also used `AsyncPostBackTrigger` but that also doesn't work i.e. doesn't upload file so the only way is `PostBackTrigger` but that refreshes whole page.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ScriptManager` along with the update panel control. `ScriptManager` should be placed before the `UpdatePanel`. You can refer [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.